# remove_if from vector of strings

Tags: algorithm, c++11

I need to remove some elements from a vector of strings if any of the strings contain a certain word.

How can I write the unary predicate for `remove_if`?

Here is code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool remove_if_found(string word)
{
   // ???
}

int main()
{
vector<string> data {
                        { "the guitar has six strings" },
                        { "the violin has four strings" },
                        { "the the violin is more difficult to learn" },
                        { "saxophones are a family of instruments" },
                        { "the drum is a set of percussions" },
                        { "the trumpet is a brass" }
};

cout << data.size() << endl;   // output: 6

remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), remove_if_found("violin"));  // error

cout << data.size() << endl;    // output should be: 4

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your vector isn't going to change size unless you erase the values marked to be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the expression `remove_if_found("violin")` returns a `bool` which cannot be passed to `std::remove_if`.

The easiest solution for you would be to change `remove_if_found` as such:

```
void remove_if_found(vector<string>& vec, const string& word)
{
    vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&word](const string& el) {
        // check if the word is contained within the string
        return el.find(word) != std::string::npos; 
    }), vec.end()); 
}
```

which takes a reference to the vector as well as the string to look for and does the removal as normal.

Then in `main` you just call it as such:

```
remove_if_found(data, "violin");
```

The reason for the erase+remove usage in the `remove_if_function` is important. `std::remove_if` merely moves the elements you wish to remove to the end of the vector and returns an iterator to the first of those (re)moved elements. On the other hand `std::vector::erase` takes two iterators - the returned one from `std::remove_if` iterator and `vec.end()` and actually erases them from the vector.

Comment: Consider also explaining the erase/remove idiom, otherwise the second size will still be 6.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for the suggestion, provided an explanation.

Comment: @Sergio If the answer indeed helped solve your question, do accept it so the question can be closed.